# PyInstaller error: 'PyiModuleGraph' object has no attribute 'edgeData'

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create an executable from a python script using PyInstaller, but I'm getting the following error

```
File "/Users/cmustata/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/PyInstaller/lib/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1225, in _updateReference
ed = self.edgeData(fromnode, tonode)
AttributeError: 'PyiModuleGraph' object has no attribute 'edgeData'
```

This seems to be related to PyInstaller itself and not my script, so I'm at a loss about how to fix it.

I'm running this on `MacOS`, with `PyInstaller` installed using `pip`. Python is system installed 2.7.10

Comment: I managed to work around this by installing version 3.3, but I have no idea why that was needed.

Answer (score 3):

When I install Pyinstaller on MacOS, terminal prompt this warning:

> macholib 1.11 has requirement altgraph>=0.15, but you'll have altgraph 0.10.2 which is incompatible.

However, I ignored it.

When using Pyinstaller, the error you mentioned occurred too.

So, for compatible version of altgraph, just uninstall altgraph and reinstall it.

Everything will be ok.

> sudo pip uninstall altgraph

and then

> sudo pip install altgraph

Comment: If, like me, you can't use sudo or run into other permission errors, you can just use the `--upgrade` flag i.e. `pip install --upgrade altgraph`